# Oracle Enterprise Manager login return page issue

Tags: oracle, weblogic, soa

After server re-boot I have problem to login to EM where I am again redirected to login page. But if I stop all services, then start just **ORACLE base_domain_AdminServer** service, log-in to EM I do not have this problem.

Once logged in when I start **ORACLE base_domain_soa_server1** everything looks OK and I can login normal until next reboot.

```
ENV:
Oracle SOA Suite 11.1.1.9.0
JDK 7.251
Windows 2012R2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the specific test environment that this was built for we use server back and forth in time via snapshoot and it turned out that problem was virtual server was picking up Today's date/time during boot but then synced back to the required/test time while Oracle services were starting. This messed up SOA. Disabling time sync from host (VMware) fixed issue.